# Check if conversation for specified participants in group chat application already exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing chat application supporting group chats. When creating group chat you specify recipients and click "Create" which creates group chat for recipients.
When user selects recipients where all recipients already exists in some existing group chat I would like to redirect to it instead of creating new one meaning each group chat has unique participants. I don't know how to check if such conversation already exists.

chat_participants table:

```
id | user_id | group_chat_id
1  | alice   | 1
2  | bob     | 1
3  | alice   | 2 // chat just with alice
4  | bob     | 3 // chat just with bob
```

When user tries to create new chat group for user ids ["alice", "bob"] I want to get id of existing group chat with these participants where all of these participants must be included and no one else in our case its group chat with id `1`.

How would you write such a sql query? I am using postgresql but any sql dialect is fine. The query should support any number of user ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check using:

```
select cp.group_chat_id
from chat_participants cp
group by cp.group_chat_id
having array_agg(user_id order by user_id) = @array_of_your_users;
```

You can pass in a parameter array to the `having` clause.  The `user_id`s should be ordered the same way in both arrays.